# Trigger a remote setTimeout Cloud Function Request

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, settimeout

I'm using firebase and would like to update a value no matter what happens using a HttpRequest Cloud function ( connection error, tab or browser closed ).

I thought of a setTimeout but this doesn't solve the issue as if anything happens the request will fail as it is related to client side.

Then my idea was to send the request on a remote server ( a bit like a cron job ) that should perform at a certain delay ( let's say 30 minutes ) but that would cancel the previous request in queue ( based on userID and request path )

How could I achieve that and is this possible?

example:

```
request number 1 -> www.myrequest with { userUID:1, data:{size:1}}
request time:12:01
request number 2 -> www.myrequest with { userUID:1, data:{size:30}}
request time:12:02
```

request 2 cancels request 1 and gets executed 30 minutes later

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the initial goal: "a value no matter what happens using a HttpRequest Cloud function ( connection error, tab or browser closed )." 
Do you mean you want to receive a client disconnect on the server?

Comment: @HugoGresse I mean I would like to send an a cloud function http request to a queue each time a user types in a new value (this could a 1 second interval). each time the remote server adds a request to the queue it would cancel the previous request. Thanks in advance. ( this is to avoid making to many request and solve the issue of a request not being sent if any erros occurs)

Comment: why not using a `debounce` method which will make this process on the client side?

Comment: @HugoGresse because if user closes the tab or the browser the request won't be sent

Comment: I believe having cloud functions staying up for a long time could be somewhat expensive. You may want to either store those requests on a database (like Firestore) with a timestamp linked to each one within a {userId} collection. Or use a real queue solution like Kafka.

Comment: Because each time you call an HTTP cloud functions, it will start a new one without possibility to communicate with each others. A soltuon for this will be to have a real server where a setTimeout will be a solution.

Comment: @HugoGresse thank you for the hint, I'll do a bit of research with what you gave me and get back to you. Thanks